# Highcharts stacked column with 2 axes from same data

Tags: highcharts, stacked, multiple-axes

I want to have a stacked column chart with one column of data with 4 items. Each  item has two measures associated with it, say a percentage of total and a dollar value.

For example,

Item    %       $

A       42%     $15.00

B       33%     $12.00

C       14%      $5.00

D       11%      $4.00

Is it possible to show the 4 items in a stacked column, with each item appearing once. The chart's left axis would have percentage labels (totaling 100%) and the right axis would have dollar labels (totaling $36).

Comment: Have you checked https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes?

Comment: Add a linked axis to the main axis, define same tick positions for the both axes, for the axis which should show percents use a labels formatter to replace values with computed percents - see the example https://jsfiddle.net/f31qjzs1/

Comment: Most of the examples with dual axes are for charts that show two different types of data each with its own measure (eg, rainfall and temperature). What I want is one kind of data with two measures. I think the jsfiddle.net/f31qjzs1 looks very promising.

Thanks!